# BlackBerry 10 Cascades - Running app on the simulator

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry development and ran into this problem several times and cannot find a solution.

When I try to run an empty cascades project just with a simple HelloWorld label I get the following error

```
Deployment Failed: Info: Sending request: Install and Launch
Info: Action: Install and Launch
Info: Debug native: on
Info: File size: 190910
Info: Installing com.example.HelloWorld.testDev__HelloWorld7d1bfe91...
Info: Processing 190910 bytes
```

I'm using Momentics, VMware running BB10 Dev Alpha Sim and followed all the instructions here. http://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/setting_up.html

I made sure my build config is set to Simulator-Debug and not even the example projects are able to run on the simulator.

Edit: I am not sure if this bit of info helps but when I try to run the application, the Progress hangs at 91% before the error dialog appears.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not setting the development Mode (like current Development Mode Simulator or Device) . I also getting the issue that Project Compile but not able to run on virtual Machine , today I sort the issue . check out the link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Native-Development/BB10-Native-Cascades-SDK-not-connecting-to-Alpha-BB10-simulator/td-p/1719865/page/5

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I set the build config to Simulator-Debug. However I tried to add the simulator manually by not using the auto-discover and typing the IP address. I am still getting the error even after adding the Simulator manually and I am making doubly sure I set the build settings to Simulator.