# Running my application in Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-simulator, blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

[image: Error Image]I am newbie in Blackberry 10 development
I have tried to run a GE / Cascade sample application but it has thrown the error as seen in image
'Syncing and starting the application has encountered a problem '
I am using BB10_0_10.261 simulator
I have skipped the Set Debug Token part . Is it a necessing for running in a Blackberry Simulator ??

I have set it in Simultor Debug mode . But its still not working ... What is the problem 
I have followed the [BlackBerry 10 Cascades - Running app on the simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886073/blackberry-10-cascades-running-app-on-the-simulator) too but its not working .

Comment: This error seem to happen for a lot of causes, but more generally because your PC has few memory for the simulator to run. Try closing all other programs and whenever this error happens, try again. Sometimes it needs about 3 trials to work...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a debug token if the projects build configuration is set to simulator debug.

*picture of error uploaded after this comment:* I am sure there is a details button on the error dialog with some more info.
Perhaps click it, and paste the output here...

[This link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ViNlh6RqvQ) should help you get your environment setup properly

You can skip to about 3:20 if you are impatient :)

The tutorials are quite good for newbies.

Comment: i get the following error message in details : Deployment Failed: Info: Sending request: Install and Launch
Info: Action: Install and Launch
Info: Debug native: on
Info: File size: 190988
Info: Installing com.example.First_project.testDev_rst_projecte3505239...
Info: Processing 190988 bytes